# Using two Not in select

Tags: julia

I want to exclude some columns in a dataframe:

```
neatDf = select(df, :Response_ID, Not([:IP_Address, :Progress, :Finished, :User_Language, :Distribution_Channel, :Response_Type]))
```

The above works. However, when I want to include a second Not to exclude columns using a Regex, it doesn't work:

```
neatDf = select(df, :Response_ID, Not([:IP_Address, :Progress, :Finished, :User_Language, :Distribution_Channel, :Response_Type]), Not(r"^Recipient"))
```

Can I use two `Not` in a row like above?

Comment: When using multiple arguments, the columns selected by each argument are ORed, i.e. when using two `Not()`s like in second example, which have disjoint columns specified, their NOTs will include *all* columns. Is this the result you get? What is the result you expect?

Comment: Two ways that I know of are: you can do a double select like: `select(select(df, Not([:Column1, :Column2])), Not(r"MyRegex"))`. Or you can use `Cols` instead: `select(df, Cols(c -> !in(c, ["Column1", "Column2"]) && !contains(c, r"MyRegex")))`. There maybe a better way though, so I'll wait to see if someone chimes in with a better answer before posting this as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to drop a union of both conditions then I think the simplest is to do the following (i.e. you use `Not` on a union of selectors; you can compute such union using `Cols`):

```
select(df, :Response_ID, Not(Cols([:IP_Address, :Progress, :Finished, :User_Language, :Distribution_Channel, :Response_Type], r"^Recipient")))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think `InMemoryDatasets` package allows this, though, you should convert your DataFrame to Dataset
`using InMemoryDatasets`

`ds=Dataset(df)`

`neatds=select(ds,Not([:IP_Address, :Progress, :Finished, :User_Language, :Distribution_Channel, :Response_Type]), Not(r"^Recipient"))`